# Karabiner doesn't detect End key on Logitech MX, VSCode does

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings, karabiner

I have a Logitech MX keys keyboard (dual Mac and PC, french layout), and I'm trying to use the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys.

I'm using the "French - PC" layout in macOS.

VScode detects the <kbd>End</kbd> key just fine, and gets me to the end/beginning of line as needed, so I know it's not an hardware issue.

In Karabiner event viewer, <kbd>Insert</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd>,  <kbd>Home</kbd>,  <kbd>End</kbd>,  <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> are completely undetected (nothing happens). I'm using Karabiner 14.11.0 and Ventura 13.2.1

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: macOS doesn't use Insert at all [it doesn't even have a key for it, though some terminals app can be persuaded to use an equivalent]. Home & End are also completely unlike 'PC' & do not refer to beginning & end of line but top & bottom of page. Are you certain you're trying to translate the correct interpretations, or just wondering why they're not the same?

Comment: I want to remap those keys using Karabiner, End to ctrl+e and Home to ctrl+a so that it does what I'm used to. My problem is that karabiner doesn't detect those keystrokes at all, whereas i know macOS done at some level because it works in vsCode ...

Comment: Do you have an extended keyboard, with 10-key & physical home/end keys? Even if you do, what do you expect ctrl/e or ctrl/a to do in regular apps? They're not Mac commands & mean little outside of terminals; generally, they'll do nothing at all. I think if you want Home & End to be recognised as 'beginning & end of line' you've a lot more work to do… more so as Mac doesn't consider 'sentences' in 'lines'.

Comment: @Tetsujin ctrl+E goes to the end of the current line on my mac, much like what the End key does on windows (and yes, I've got an extended keyboard with a keypad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that Then creating `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` and adding these worked after a restart of my session:

```
{
    "\UF729"  = "moveToBeginningOfLine:";
    "\UF72B"  = "moveToEndOfLine:";
}
```